# Create JavaScript array from excel data using JavaScript and JSON

Tags: javascript, html, json

I'm trying to read and parse an excel file and create a JavaScript array object with the data.
The excel file will look like:

```
AA11 AA22 AN65
AB11 AB22 AN64
...
```

And I want the JavaScript array to look like:

```
[[AA11, AA22, AN65], [AB11, AB22, AN64],...]
```

So far I have the following code:

```
<input type="file" id="input" accept=".xls,.xlsx,.ods" />
<a id="result"></a>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#input").on("change", function(e) {
                var file = e.target.files[0];
                if (!file) return;

                var FR = new FileReader();
                function byDocument(e) {
                    var data = new Uint8Array(e.target.result);
                    var workbook = XLSX.read(data, { type: "array" });
                    var firstSheet = workbook.Sheets[workbook.SheetNames[0]];

                    var result = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(firstSheet, { header: 1 });
                    var output = document.getElementById("result");
                    output.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(result, null, 2);
                    window.alert(result);
                    window.alert(result.type);
                    var array;
                    array = output.innerHTML;
                    output.parentNode.removeChild(output);
                    return array;
                }
                FR.onload = function(e) {
                    array = byDocument(e);
                    window.alert(array);
                    array.type = Array;
                    window.alert(array.type);
                    window.alert(array.length);
                };
                FR.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
            });

</script>
```

This outputs text on the document that looks like an array, but when I try to store the data in a variable and index the `array`, it views the element array as some sort of string, or undefined. I'm wondering how to parse the excel file, or convert the JSON string, so that it behaves like a JavaScript array, which I could then index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it should be `array = result` instead of `array = output.innerHTML`. Or, at least, `array = JSON.parse(ourput.innerHTML)`, because `innerHTML` is not an array, it's a string (you got it by `JSON.strigify` before).

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are already turning your result into JSON here:

```
var result = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(firstSheet, { header: 1 });
```

According to the documents of [xlsx](https://docs.sheetjs.com/#json) this will convert your excel file into workable JSON. So `result` might be the value you need to return instead of `array` in your `byDocument` function.

Answer (score 0):

The line `output.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(result, null, 2);` will turn the object into JSON and put it in the DOM.

`const myJSObject = JSON.parse(myJSON)` will return a JavaScript object and assign it to a variable.

I took a few of the DOM lines out of your function to make it less confusing, so you could try replacing your function with:

```
function byDocument(e) {
    var data = new Uint8Array(e.target.result);
    var workbook = XLSX.read(data, { type: "array" });
    var firstSheet = workbook.Sheets[workbook.SheetNames[0]];

    var result = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(firstSheet, { header: 1 });
    var array;
    array = result
    return array;
}
```